# Windows folder sharing access after startup

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, network-shares

Here's the problem: A windows 7 pc's drive D is shared on the workgroup. we are using it to store common files needed by everyone in the office. And I happen to be the first in the morning to need that shared drive. So, instead of going everyday to that pc to turn it on, I activated auto power on in the bios to power it on 30 minutes prior to office time ( Yes, I am lazy :) ). But the problem is I can't see the shared drive unless I login on the pc sharing that drive. Any way to mitigate this!

P.S: my pc has windows 10.

Comment: You might consider to use wake-on-Lan. For your reference:https://superuser.com/questions/508958/mapping-a-network-drive-in-windows-so-that-it-only-reconnects-when-accessed   https://www.groovypost.com/howto/enable-wake-on-lan-windows-10/

Comment: No, the pc is already turned on and it is not set to go to sleep automatically either. I can even remotely access it with rdp any time. The problem is the shared drive won't be visible to other computers unless i login to the pc either remotely or at the pc locally. One more thing to note is that the said pc have two user account. Can that be ralated?